# Showing that $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}&, (x, y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0, & ,(x, y)=(0, 0) \end{cases}$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}&, (x, y)\ne (0,0) \\ 0, & ,(x, y)=(0, 0) \end{cases}$$ is differentiable.
I went as follows: on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ it is obvious that the partial derivatives are continuous (we are differentiating some "composition" of elementary functions), so $f$ is differentiable of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus{(0,0)}$. We are left to check $f$'s differentiability at $(0,0)$.
We have $$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$ because $$|\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le | \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\le y$$
Is this a correct way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit that you need to check is

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-f'_x(0,0)\cdot x - f'_y(0,0)\cdot y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},
$$

so you first need to compute $f'_x(0,0)$ and $f'_y(0,0)$ using the definition. But, since in this case $f'_x(0,0)=f'_y(0,0)=0$, your conclusion is correct.

---

$$
f'_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{0,0}{x} = 0$$

$$
f'_y(0,0)=\lim_{y\to 0} \dfrac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y} = \lim_{y\to 0}\dfrac{0,0}{y} = 0
$$

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to write the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, thank you! I was more worried that my observation regarding the continuity of the partial derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ would be a bit unrigorous, but I think that it is quite okay, right?

Comment: Your solution is ok, you should only mention that $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} y= 0$... that is why you can prove that  your limit is zero.